# How to hide or disable(readonly) a column in kendo grid during Insert?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a column(DefaultValueColumn) that should contain a default value.
That column, during insert/add, user should not be able to input a value in that column.

I have tried to use javascript to make the column read only.

```
    function grid_onInsert() {
    $('[name="DefaultValueColumn"]').attr("readonly", true);

    $('#gridKendo').data('kendoGrid').addRow();
    clearErrorMsg();
    }
```

But the script doesn't work.
Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 function grid_onInsert() {
    var grid = $('#gridKendo').data('kendoGrid');
    var data = grid.dataSource.at(index of DefaultValueColumn);
    data.fields["DefaultValueColumn"].editable = false;
    $('#gridKendo').data('kendoGrid').addRow();
    clearErrorMsg();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your code but I get this error in index of DefaultValueColumn it says Expected ')'